# How do I flip a video that is recorded upside down

Tags: ios, ipad

I recorded a video upside down on my iPad Air 2. How do I flip it. I twisted it with my fingers, but it won't stay.

Answer (score 3):

This works on my Mac with OS X Yosemite 10.10.4.
Open it in Quicktime.
Under the edit menu should be options for rotating. Once you have done that just export the rotated video in the format you want.